# Libsvm in matlab for heart beats

Tags: matlab, testing, signals, libsvm

I have 3 different heart beats, normal, Left block and right block. I have 20 beats of each. I want to do training on the 60 heart beats and then test on a few different heart beats. I want the program to tell me if it is normal, Left or right block. All i have is a 60 x 300 matrix where the first 20 rows are normal, then left, the right block.

How do i make training labels?
They have to be in a special format but i have no idea how to create this for training.

I even emailed the creator of libsvm but i haven't heard back.

Can somewhere help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say 1 = normal, 2 = left, and 3 = right then labels is

```
labels = [ones(20,1); 2*ones(20,1); 3*ones(20,1)];
```

Comment: But with libsvm, the labels are in this format, 1 1:2 2:3 4:6 1...etc. I don't know what or how to create these labels.

Comment: Isn't that only if you have the labels in a training file? I have used libsvm in octave (which I assume is going to be identical to matlab) and my answer is how I made my labels.